# Setting fixed-width tables, varying text length on HTML page

Tags: html

i am trying to make it such that the code will produce the below image, but it seems something is off with my table widths...any fixes? I'm still a n00b at HTML, thanks a million!! will upvote and accept the solution that fix my problem 100%

[image: Image of expected result]

Code For table:

```
     <table  style="table-layout: fixed width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tr>

        <td colspan="1" width="250"></td>
        <td colspan="2" width="10"><span>Postanschrift</span></td>
    <td colspan="3" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Nein&#160;</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Ja</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" width="15"></td>
    <td colspan="2" width="10"><span>SMS / MMS</span></td>
    <td colspan="3" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Nein&#160;</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Ja</span></td>

 </table>
 <table  style="table-layout: fixed width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tr>

        <td colspan="1" width="250"></td>
        <td colspan="2" width="10"><span>Telefon</span></td>
    <td colspan="3" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Nein&#160;</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Ja</span></td>
        <td colspan="1" width="15"></td>
    <td colspan="2" width="10"><span>E-Mail</span></td>
    <td colspan="3" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Nein&#160;</span></td>
    <td colspan="2" width="5"><input type="radio" value="F" <span>&#160;Ja</span></td>          
 </table>
```

This is the image of the result of the expected code...pretty messed up :S[image]

As you can see, the indentation before Postanschrift and Telefon works just fine ...however the later column widths are no longer fixed like in the image of the 'expected result'

EDIT 1: Using WebDevNewbie's code snippet, here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style tag in `<table>` was not complete, and making your table fixed with your widths is what is crushing it all together. Removing the `table-layout: fixed` solved it for the most part, and I also had to widen the SMS / MMS `<td>` due to the spaces, it would push them to different lines.

Changing the widths on all of them would be a good bet.

```
<table style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;"></td>        
        <td width="100px">
            <span>Postanschrift</span>
        </td>
        <td width="60px" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
            <input type="radio" value="F"/>
            <span>&#160;Nein&#160;</span>
        </td>
        <td width="40px">
            <input type="radio" value="F"/>
            <span>&#160;Ja</span>
        </td>
        <td width="30px" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;"></td>
        <td width="100px">
            <span>SMS / MMS</span>
        </td>
        <td width="60px" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
            <input type="radio" value="F"/>
            <span>&#160;Nein&#160;</span>
        </td>
        <td width="45px">
            <input type="radio" value="F"/>
            <span>&#160;Ja</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: Also, all the `colspans` weren't needed in this case. Those are if you want a `<td>` to span more than one column, which isn't needed here. There is also an empty cell that doesn't need to be there...

EDIT: I see why you are using that blank cell, a spacer. I have update the table, the first cell has a width of 100% now, this will allow for expanding, and I have increased the other widths..

EDIT: Closed the `<input>` tags, and formatted for readability..

Comment: how do i reduce the space between Nein and Ja? also, SMS/MMS appear to be wrapped using your code...will post up the image now..

Comment: I have updated the table..


If you want them to be closer, you could put them in the same `<td>`, just increase that `<td>` width to allow for the extra space. You could also increase the width of the spacer `<td>` you have in there and the witdh's of other `<td>'s` to give the look of them being closer.


I also added color to see cells more clearly.

Comment: @bouncingHippo pls tell me you fixed your html ie made sure to close the <input> tags and <tr> tags?

Comment: @Chris I didn't even notice those when I was piecing it all together, lol.. Be sure to do what he is suggesting bouncingHippo, I will update my code above to reflect that.

Comment: yeah the input tags are all closed ie <input type..../> and same for the </tr> too :)